# Scheme: how to check if void

Tags: scheme

I get this error :

```
cdr: expects argument of type <pair>; given #<void>
```

and checking if `(null? argument)` isn't working
I searched alot for `void?` function , but I could find anything 
so , any ideas ppl :)
thanks a million in advance

Comment: @Charlie: That error message is a dead ringer for Racket (or PLT Scheme, if the OP is using an older pre-Racket version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `pair?` to see if you can `cdr` it. There is no specific check for void, since it's essentially a phantom type.

Answer (score 0):

Chris's answer is good because you really want to be checking for a pair to cdr, but for future reference, you may be able to do `(eq? (void) (void))` if `(void)` is available or `(eq? (if #f #t) (if #f #t))` if you want to define your own `(void)`.

Comment: I don't think any standard guarantees that comparing two instances of unspecific values with `eq?` will return a true value. So, such an approach is not going to be portable.